# LogCat acting patchy

Tags: android

The LogCat output in eclipse suddenly started weird. It sometimes shows all the output as expected. Other times it just doesn't show anything - is **completely blank**.

After some internet research, I thought Mylyn plugin might be responsible. So I tried de-selecting "Mylyn Tasks UI" & "Mylyn Team UI" on eclipse Window --> Preferences --> General --> Startup and Shutdown --> programs that are started at startup.

No Luck. Has anyone else encountered & solved this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has happened to me once or twice and I solved easily by going to the devices view and made sure I had the right device highlighted.

```
Window > Show View > Other... > Android > Devices
```